# add screen width function for new effect

Tags: javascript

I need to add/edit this existing javascript function for screen widths < 769px

Here is current function to show / hide the tbody. By default the tables on this page are all shown , and when you click a + or - sign on the caption the collapse and expand.

```
function toggle_display (id) {
   var table = document.getElementById(id);
   if (table) {
      var children = table.getElementsByTagName("TBODY");
      var new_status = '-';
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         var display = children[i].style.display ? '' : 'none';
         if (display == 'none') {
            new_status = '+';
         }
         children[i].style.display = display;
         var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + year + "/save_setting?L=" + league_id + "&TITLE=DISPLAY&VALUE=" + id + ":" + display;
         makeHttpRequest(url);
      }
      // change the innerHTML to [-] or [+] accordingly...
      var spans = table.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
      for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
         var currentClass = spans[i].getAttribute("className");
         if (currentClass == null || currentClass.length == 0) {
            currentClass = spans[i].getAttribute("class");
         }
         if (currentClass != null && currentClass.length > 0 && currentClass.indexOf("module_expand") >= 0) {
            spans[i].innerHTML = "[" + new_status + "]";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to apply the reverse logic for screen width < 769

```
   if (screen.width < 769) {
      // have display:none to all tbody by default and then expand to remove that style when clicked
   }
```

Any help on this , i'm not fluent with javascript , just a novice looking for some help to make a quick change

Here is the click event function for the + / - signs within the captions , but i don't think this needs any edits , but posting for reference

```
function set_up_double_click_events () {
   var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
   for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
      var thisClass = tables[i].getAttribute("className");
      var thisId = tables[i].getAttribute("id");
      if (! thisClass || thisClass.length == 0) {
         thisClass = tables[i].getAttribute("class");
      }
      if (thisClass && (thisClass.indexOf("report") >= 0 || thisClass.indexOf("playoffbracket") >= 0)) {
         var captions = tables[i].getElementsByTagName("CAPTION");
         for (var j = 0; j < captions.length; j++) {
            if (typeof moduleExpand == "undefined" || moduleExpand == 'Doubleclick') {
               captions[j].ondblclick=function() {
                  toggle_display(this.parentNode.getAttribute("id"));
               }
            } else if (typeof moduleExpand != "undefined" && moduleExpand == 'PlusMinus') {
               // add the + sign here...
               var span = document.createElement("span");
               span.setAttribute("className", "module_expand");
               span.setAttribute("class", "module_expand");
               span.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible;");
               span.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
               span.onclick=function() {
                  toggle_display(this.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
               }
               span.innerHTML = "[-]";
               captions[j].insertBefore(span, captions[j].firstChild);
               // alert("innerHTML: " + captions[j].innerHTML);
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a combination of media queries and javascript like so:

- By default, show all `tbody` elements
- By default, hide all `toggle` buttons
- When screen size is narrow:

  - Hide all `tbody` elements
  - Show all `toggle` buttons
  - When `tbody` has certain class, show it
- Toggle button toggles the class `tbody` needs to be always visible

(resize in full screen to test, press "Full Page")

```js
document
  .querySelector(".toggle")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document
      .querySelector("tbody")
      .classList.toggle("is-expanded");
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
}
@media (max-width: 760px) {
  tbody {
    display: none;
  }
  tbody.is-expanded {
    display: table-row-group;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="toggle">toggle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>I'm a table cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ty I will test out tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be easier using CSS and media queries.

The default style for `tbody` could look like this:

```
tbody {
  display: none;
}
```

Then at resolutions >= 769:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  tbody {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty will test tomorrow and see if this or the JavaScript solution is better